# No errors, and program runs, but does absolutely JACK

Tags: java, android

This is a pretty straight forward little program at this point.  Keeping it simple for now.  Concept is simple, there are a bunch of radio buttons, for different scales popular in model building.  You tick the appropriate radio button, enter the real size in inches, and hit calculate and it spits out the scale size in inches.  Simple division, but it will get me the information I need if I can get it to work.  So far it compiles cleanly, and it runs fine, you check the radio button, enter a number, and hit the calculate button and it just sits there and does nothing.  The following is the code I added(not including the imports of course).

```
 public void onButtonClick(View v)
{
    int n1, result = 0;
    EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextSize);
    TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    RadioButton rb144 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton144);
    RadioButton rb72 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton72);
    RadioButton rb48 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton48);
    RadioButton rb35 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton35);
    RadioButton rb32 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton32);
    RadioButton rb25 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton25);
    RadioButton rb24 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton24);
    n1 = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
    if(rb144.isChecked()){
        result = n1 / 144;
    }else if(rb72.isChecked()){
        result = n1 / 72;
    }else if(rb48.isChecked()){
        result = n1 / 48;
    }else if(rb35.isChecked()){
        result = n1 / 35;
    }else if(rb32.isChecked()){
        result = n1 / 32;
    }else if(rb25.isChecked()){
        result = n1 / 25;
    }else if(rb24.isChecked()){
        result = n1 / 24;
    }
    t1.setText(Integer.toString(result));
```

Comment: Side-note: integer division.

Comment: What is the real value you're entering? Which radio button is set?

Comment: post your code in which you're call the onButtonClick() method

Comment: Any errors in your logCat?

Comment: It's basically dividing whatever is in the box with a number based upon which radio button is checked.  There are no errors, but I think No_Rulz might have got the biggest issue here correct.  While there is a click listener and everthing, I have done all the suggestions with the code and no luck.  I realized there doesn't seem to be a single thing telling it what to do when that specific button is clicked.

Comment: The code by A.R. did nothing, and the code by Nik did nothing but throw errors in the code itself, red squiggles everywhere.  Couldn't make it work.  I realized what the on button click was sorry, I'm tired tonight.  Aside from the imports and the layout code, the code you see is what is there.  There is nothing else.  It's a simple app at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Your method name for the OnClickListener() is incorrect. It should be onClick(...), not onButtonClick(...). See example:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //hello button

        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        tv.setText("hello button!");

    }
  });
```

In the future be sure to add the @Override annotation when you're defining these methods, that way if you misspell something the compiler will detect that you've not actually overridden something.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

I made few changes in your code.

```
 public void onButtonClick(View v)
{
        float n1,result = 0;
        EditText e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextSize);
        TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        RadioButton rb144 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton144);
        RadioButton rb72 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton72);
        RadioButton rb48 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton48);
        RadioButton rb35 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton35);
        RadioButton rb32 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton32);
        RadioButton rb25 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton25);
        RadioButton rb24 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton24);

        n1 =Float.parseFloat(e1.getText().toString());

        if(rb144.isChecked()){
            result = n1 / 144;
        }else if(rb72.isChecked()){
            result = n1 / 72;
        }else if(rb48.isChecked()){
            result = n1 / 48;
        }else if(rb35.isChecked()){
            result = n1 / 35;
        }else if(rb32.isChecked()){
            result = n1 / 32;
        }else if(rb25.isChecked()){
            result = n1 / 25;
        }else if(rb24.isChecked()){
            result = n1 / 24;
        }
        t1.setText(String.valueOf(result));
}
```

Note: For better programming approach you nee to define your stuff of finding ids of your views like radio button, edittext etc in onCreate() instead of on Button Click.